# For concave functions $f(y)≤f(x)+f′(x)(y−x),∀x,y$ but..

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

For concave functions $f(y)≤f(x)+f′(x)(y−x),∀x,y$,][1] (linear approximation) but this can also be written as $f′(x)≥(f(y)−f(x))/(y−x)∀x,y$, but isn't this only applicable when $y≥x$ and not when $x≤y$. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmW9s.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the second inequality is only applicable with $y> x$. For $y< x$, the inequality is reversed, $f'(x)\leq (f(y) - f(x))/(y-x)$ as when you divide the $(y-x)$ from both sides to get the inequality, this time it is negative.